# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, crash

> "react": "17.0.2",
> "react-native": "0.67.4",

Crash reporter

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main

 result: 0

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.chinatower, PID: 30642
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so
    SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.chinatower/lib-main flags = 1]
    SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/com.chinatower-mkTH-LjSf-hvYj8ei0eeKw==/lib/x86 flags = 0]
    SoSource 2: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /vendor/lib flags = 2]
    SoSource 3: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib flags = 2]
    Native lib dir: /data/app/com.chinatower-mkTH-LjSf-hvYj8ei0eeKw==/lib/x86
 result: 0
```

after searching around for a decent XX solution and found that everything out there was difficult to use.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.
2022-05-31 09:25:35

issue:

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'assets/cfg/a/CustomIndex'
        exclude '**.**'  
    }
```

Comment: Did you try disabling Hermes, at least temporarily ?

Comment: Not yet, I found out what the problem was

Comment: What was it, can you tell ?

Comment: the   packagingOptions -> exclude 'assets/cfg/a/CustomIndex'